# CP sat and solution search dead end

Tags: python, runtime, or-tools, cp-sat

Just wondering what CP SAT does when it selects a branch which does not lead to global optimum? For instance, a code minimizing an objective returns:

```
Solution 0, time = 1.05 s, objective = 11700
Solution 1, time = 1.59 s, objective = 9200
Solution 2, time = 4.54 s, objective = 9100
Solution 3, time = 5.14 s, objective = 8600
Solution 4, time = 6.44 s, objective = 7600
Solution 5, time = 8.04 s, objective = 7100
Solution 6, time = 8.72 s, objective = 6000
Solution 7, time = 10.44 s, objective = 5900
Solution 8, time = 15.67 s, objective = 1600
Solution 9, time = 16.29 s, objective = 200
```

I understand it ignores solutions with greater objective value in minimizing context.

Below is the setup.

```
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 100
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 16
```

Since the code finished in 40 seconds, can one assume it enumerated all solutions? I was unable to  use enumerate_all_solutions parameter in combination with num_search_workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all solvers, it prunes branches as soon as possible.
Note that search in a SAT solver is not a tree search.

After 40s, it proved that the solution is optimal. Luckily, it does not need to enumerate all solutions to do so.

Note: linearization_level = 0 is bizarre. Does it change anything ?

Comment: Copied it from samples. Simulation indicated it even slows down the execution (removed from original post). Is there smth to read more about these params, such as recommended setup for problem categories? Found only https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto